# multiline textarea in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textarea

I want a multiline text area using VB.net. I have used a text area in html before, but I have never used one in VB.net.

I tried:

```
<textarea id="TA" cols="100" rows="20"></textarea>
```

But I cannot change the value of textarea using my code behind file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a [ASP.Net TextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.aspx) with `TextMode = MultiLine`.

[TextBox.TextMode Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.textmode.aspx)